# unrecognized usb passthrough to windows server 2012 r2 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2012-r2, kvm-virtualization, xen, virtualbox

I have a ubuntu 16.04 lts on a intel NUC machine.

I want to use a TV usb tuner, in Japan, which only works for Windows.

So, I'm trying to install a windows server 2012 r2 guest VM on the ubuntu host.

I looked for vm tools such as kvm, xen, virtualbox, vmware.

Which tool is appropriate to **pass an unrecognized usb** to the windows server guest easily?

The ubuntu host and the windows guest will be run 24 hours/day as servers.

Any working tools are OK. Have you ever seen working, or can you guess which one will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `VirtualBox` and set up it with Windows Server. You can download Oracle Virtual Box with this link [link](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

In the web there're many tutorials for do it, I can recommend you this guide for [virtualbox](https://www.howtoforge.com/virtualbox-2-how-to-pass-through-usb-devices-to-guests-on-an-ubuntu-8.10-host)

Comment: Thanks! I did. It seems to work for an unrecognized usb. I thought I had failed last time.